# Подключение socket в разных сетях

Tags: python, сокет

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста чего не хватает или что не так делаю? Пытаюсь подключиться по сокетам в разных сетях. Nat forwarding роутера на проброс портов тоже настроил, но соединение не устанавливается, в чем проблема?('0.0.0.0' у сервера тоже пробовал, не помогло)

```
# CLIENT
import socket
client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect(('тут мой ip внешний', 4444))

# SERVER
import socket
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server.bind(('192.168.1.105', 4444))
server.listen(1)
print('[!]Waiting for incoming connections')
connection, address = server.accept()
print('[!]Got a connection from {str(address)}')
```

настройки роутера(tp-link)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А ваш интернет-провайдер выдаёт вам внешний IP-адрес, к которому будет в принципе возможно подключаться? Название «LTE» намекает, что скорее всего нет

Comment: у меня роутер через симкарту работает

Comment: Ваши роутер и сим-карта ни на что не повлияют, если ваш интернет-провайдер в принципе не предоставляет вам внешний IP-адрес

Answer (score 0):

0.0.0.0 обязательно. На LTE редко дают белые адреса. На адресах 100/8,10/8,127/8,172.16/12,192.168/16 маршрутизация в другую сеть не получится.

Выполните трассировку и скорее всего увидеть после вошего роутера ещё один на 100.х.х.х, на котором нат не сделать.

Купите белую виртуалку или попробуйте heroku

Comment: у меня сейчас роутер с симкартой, а если использовать обычный как в квартирах, у него будет белый адрес?

Comment: @Ant1dot это зависит не от роутера, не от сим-карты и не от квартиры, а от интернет-провайдера и условий, которые он предоставляет

Comment: а как белую купить?

Comment: https://vdsina.ru/?partner=1xv5fk5qgv вот тут 6 рублей в день минималке.

Comment: https://justhost.ru/?ref=3840 вот тут от 3,50 в день